# Coloring a Tree

Tags: algorithm

There is a coloring a tree problem in one of contest which i could not solve.
Problem Statement:
We have to Color a tree such that the no two adjacent vertex is having the same color and the cost of coloring the tree is minimum
 
[Problem Link](https://www.facebook.com/hackercup/problems.php?pid=759650454070547&round=344496159068801)

I have no idea what algorithm should i used in such type of problems
PLease the algorithm behind this.

Comment: Unless you mean something different than I think when you say "adjacent", this is very simple. Every tree is a bipartite graph.

Comment: @RafaelLerm  would you please explain

Comment: Every tree is also a bipartite graph, which means it can be colored using only two colors. If you look for algorithms for coloring such graphs (or even checking if a graph is bipartite), you should find them easily.

Comment: The only way to color a tree using two colors is to change to the other color every time you change level. So if node X is color 1 then both its parent and children must be color 2.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was more than just coloring a tree since there was a minimization problem. You can read the editorial here: https://www.facebook.com/notes/1047761065239794/